# Domain User access with local TFS Service Account

Tags: tfs

Does the TFS Service Account have to be a Domain Account in order to assign Domain Users to Collections and Projects?

I've added a local group that contains a Domain User and now experiencing the following warning in the event log:

```
One or more errors occured when Team Foundation Server attempted to synchronize the following identity:
(...) My-Local-Group-Name
(...) The-SID-of-the-Domain-Account
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In order to talk to the Active Directory Domain Controller, the service account must be part of the domain. Otherwise only local users can be added. To work around it and if your machine is domain joined, you can install it as Local Service or Network Service, that way it uses your machine link to AD.